# Grid Lines are displayed in Jasper Report while creating Docx Report

Tags: jasper-reports, docx

Code to generate Docx report is below:

```
JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
exporter.setParameter(JRDocxExporterParameter.FRAMES_AS_NESTED_TABLES, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRDocxExporterParameter.FLEXIBLE_ROW_HEIGHT, Boolean.TRUE);

exporter.exportReport();
bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

I have set content type of file being generated to - "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document".

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue by modifying settings in word,In MS Word change go in layout section and disable view greed lines.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this issue by modifying settings in word, In MS Word go in layout section and disable view greed lines.